# Rails - How to obtain an absolute URL for the site? https://example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For one of my models I have a method:

def download_url
 url = xxxxx
end

which works nicely to make /xxxx/xxxx/3

What i want to do is updated this to include an absolute URL so I can use this method in an email:

https://example.com/xxxx/xxxx/3

But I don't want to hard code. I want it to be an environment var so it works on dev & production

Comment: How about calling `root_url`, when you have a root route defined in your `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

Emails are effectively views, and can use helpers. The model shouldn't really have any knowledge about the views - instead, you should use `url_for` or one of its descendant methods in the email view template to generate a URL. Those helpers can generate absolute URLs based on the location that the application is running (and associated configuration - you'll want to set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]` in your environment file) without having to mess with environment variables and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I would define the domain as a constant in development.rb & production.rb:

```
APP_DOMAIN = "https://mysite.com"
```

And then just use this constant in your method within the model:

```
def download_url
  "#{APP_DOMAIN}/download/#{id}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be ugly, but it's necessary. Rails apps don't and shouldn't know their root URL. That's a job for the web server. But, hardcoding sucks...

If you're using capistrano or some other deployment method, you can define the server host in a variable and write it out to a file that you can read from the app.